# data.getData() returns null in OnActvityResult while taking /Selecting Pictures from Camera and Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-intent-chooser

I am developing an android app, which has a profile fragment where users can upload profile picture via taking picture or selecting from gallery. For now, everything is working fine via Activity.RESULT_OK. But the problem is the onActivityResult data.getData() that is returning nothing. I have made researches on this issue to no avail.

These are the two methods contained in my editprofile fragment.

```
private void setGalleryBtn() {
    if (PermissionHandler.checkPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
        AppHelper.LogCat("Read data permission already granted.");
        new PickerBuilder(getActivity(), PickerBuilder.SELECT_FROM_GALLERY)
                .setOnImageReceivedListener(imageUri -> {
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.setData(imageUri);
                    AppHelper.LogCat("new image SELECT_FROM_GALLERY" + imageUri);
                    mEditProfilePresenter.onActivityResult(this, AppConst.SELECT_PROFILE_PICTURE, RESULT_OK, data);

                })
                .setImageName(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setImageFolderName(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setCropScreenColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .withTimeStamp(false)
                .setOnPermissionRefusedListener(() -> {
                    PermissionHandler.requestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                })
                .start();

    } else {
        AppHelper.LogCat("Please request Read data permission.");
        PermissionHandler.requestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    }

}



private void setCameraBtn() {
    if (PermissionHandler.checkPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        AppHelper.LogCat("camera permission already granted.");
        new PickerBuilder(getActivity(), PickerBuilder.SELECT_FROM_CAMERA)
                .setOnImageReceivedListener(imageUri -> {

                    AppHelper.LogCat("new image SELECT_FROM_CAMERA " + imageUri);
                    Intent data = new Intent();
                    data.setData(imageUri);
                    mEditProfilePresenter.onActivityResult(this, AppConst.SELECT_PROFILE_CAMERA, RESULT_OK, data);

                })
                .setImageName(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setImageFolderName(getActivity().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setCropScreenColor(R.color.colorPrimary)
                .withTimeStamp(false)
                .setOnPermissionRefusedListener(() -> {
                    PermissionHandler.requestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
                })
                .start();
    } else {
        AppHelper.LogCat("Please request camera  permission.");
        PermissionHandler.requestPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
    }
}
```

This is my EditProfilePresenter.onActivityResult method.

```
public void onActivityResult(Edit_profile_fragment myEdit_profile_fragment, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String imagePath = null;
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (PermissionHandler.checkPermission(myEdit_profile_fragment.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            AppHelper.LogCat("Read contact data permission already granted.");

            switch (requestCode) {
                case AppConst.SELECT_PROFILE_PICTURE:
                        imagePath = FilesManager.getPath(myEdit_profile_fragment.getActivity(), data.getData());
                    break;
                case AppConst.SELECT_PROFILE_CAMERA:
                    if (data.getData() != null) {
                        imagePath = FilesManager.getPath(myEdit_profile_fragment.getActivity(), data.getData());

                    } else {
                        try {
                            String[] projection = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, MediaStore
                                    .Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN, MediaStore.Images
                                    .ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE};
                            final Cursor cursor = myEdit_profile_fragment.getActivity().getContentResolver()
                                    .query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns
                                            .DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                                String imageLocation = cursor.getString(1);
                                cursor.close();
                                File imageFile = new File(imageLocation);
                                if (imageFile.exists()) {
                                    imagePath = imageFile.getPath();
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            AppHelper.LogCat("error" + e);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }


            if (imagePath != null) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new Pusher(AppConst.EVENT_BUS_IMAGE_PROFILE_PATH, imagePath));
            } else {
                AppHelper.LogCat("imagePath is null");
            }
        } else {
            AppHelper.LogCat("Please request Read contact data permission.");
            PermissionHandler.requestPermission(myEdit_profile_fragment.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

}
```

Please what am I getting wrong?

Comment: Have you found the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can Try this

```
if (requestCode == REQUEST_FROM_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
{
Bundle extras2 = data.getExtras();
 if (extras2 != null) {
                    // do your stuff here
                     } 
                   else {
                  // handle this case as well if data.getExtras() is null
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                   }
}
```

Hope it helps you